# Encrypting the lines in a file

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a program that opens a text file, and shifts each of the characters in the file 5 characters to the right.  It should only do this for alphanumeric characters, and leave nonalphanumerics as they are.  (ex: C becomes H) I'm supposed to be using the ASCII table to do this, and I'm having an issue when the characters wrap around.  ex: w should become b, but my program gives me a character that's in the ASCII table.  Another issue I'm having is that all the characters are printing on separate lines and I'd like them all to print on the same line.
I can't use lists or dictionaries.

This is what I have, I'm not sure how to do the final if statement

```
def main():
    fileName= input('Please enter the file name: ')
    encryptFile(fileName)


def encryptFile(fileName):
    f= open(fileName, 'r')
    line=1
    while line:
       line=f.readline()
       for char in line:
           if char.isalnum():
               a=ord(char)
               b= a + 5
               #if number wraps around, how to correct it
               if 

                print(chr(c))
            else:
                print(chr(b))
        else:
            print(char)
```

Comment: Hi, the % operator can be used for wrapping around. e.g. 0 % 2 = 1, 0 1 % 2 = 1, 2 % 2 = 0, 3 % 2 = 1, ... % takes the remainder after dividing x by y. So you can shift so a = 0, z = 25 and % 26 after adding 5

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using [str.translate](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_translate.htm):

```
In [24]: import string

In [25]: string.uppercase
Out[25]: 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'

In [26]: string.uppercase[5:]+string.uppercase[:5]
Out[26]: 'FGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDE'

In [27]: table = string.maketrans(string.uppercase, string.uppercase[5:]+string.uppercase[:5])

In [28]: 'CAR'.translate(table)
Out[28]: 'HFW'

In [29]: 'HELLO'.translate(table)
Out[29]: 'MJQQT'
```

Comment: and to use this for numbers and lower case you can reference string.lowercase + string.digits

Answer (score 1):

First, it matters if it is lower or upper case. I am going to assume here that all the characters are lower case (if they aren't, it would be easy enough to make them)

```
if b>122:
    b=122-b  #z=122
    c=b+96   #a=97
```

w=119 in ASCII and z=122 (decimal in ASCII) so 119+5=124 and 124-122=2 which is our new b, then we add that to a-1 (this takes care of if we get a 1 back,  2+96=98 and 98 is b.

For the printing on the same line, instead of printing when you have them, I would write them to a list, then create a string from that list.

e.g instead of

```
    print(chr(c))
else:
    print(chr(b))
```

I would do

```
     someList.append(chr(c))
else: 
     somList.append(chr(b))
```

then join each element of the list together into one string.

Comment: Yes I've just realized this problem with uppercase vs lowercase.  I'm supposed to make it so it could be either, so C would return H and c would return h.  Any advice for that?

Comment: I would look at the answer given by unutbu. You could write it for both upper and lowercase, and it seems to be more compact :)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a [dictionary](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=dictionary%20comprehension#dictionaries) to handle it:

```
import string
s = string.lowercase + string.uppercase + string.digits + string.lowercase[:5]
encryptionKey = {s[i]:s[i+5] for i in range(len(s)-5)}
```

The final addend to `s` (`+ string.lowercase[:5]`) adds the first 5 letters into the key. Then, we use a simple dictionary comprehension to create a key for the encryption.

Put into your code (I also changed it so you iterate through the lines rather than using `f.readline()`:

```
import string
def main():
    fileName= input('Please enter the file name: ')
    encryptFile(fileName)


def encryptFile(fileName):
    s = string.lowercase + string.uppercase + string.digits + string.lowercase[:5]
    encryptionKey = {s[i]:s[i+5] for i in range(len(s)-5)}
    f= open(fileName, 'r')
    line=1
    for line in f:
       for char in line:
           if char.isalnum():
               print(encryptionKey[char])
           else:
                print(char)
```